# Listview grouptemplate - code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, code-behind

I am looking to programatically load the group template and layout template but I am getting the following error message:

**A group placeholder must be specified on ListView 'Listview1' when the GroupTemplate is defined. Specify a group placeholder by setting its ID property to "ListView_GC$groupPlaceHolder1". The group placeholder control must also specify runat="server".**

```
    protected void Listview1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("in init");
        Listview1.ItemPlaceholderID = "ListView_UC$itemPlaceHolder1";
        Listview1.GroupPlaceholderID = "ListView_GC$groupPlaceHolder1";
        Listview1.GroupItemCount = 3;
        Listview1.LayoutTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/Controls/ThumbnailView_LayoutTemplate.ascx");
        Listview1.GroupTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/Controls/ThumbnailView_GroupTemplate.ascx");
        Listview1.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/Controls/ThumbnailView_ItemTemplate.ascx");

    }


    void Listview1_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Listview1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);


        Control newLayoutContainer = new Control();

        Listview1.LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(newLayoutContainer);
        Listview1.GroupTemplate.InstantiateIn(newLayoutContainer); 
        var userControl = newLayoutContainer.Controls[0];
        var usergControl = newLayoutContainer.Controls[1];

        userControl.ID = "ListView_UC";
        usergControl.ID = "ListView_GC";

        Listview1.Controls.Add(newLayoutContainer);

    }
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Markup for the control...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ThumbnailView_GroupTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="myproject.Controls.ThumbnailView_GroupTemplate" %>
<tr>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
</tr>

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ThumbnailView_LayoutTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="myproject.Controls.ThumbnailView_LayoutTemplate" %>
<table>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the markup of ThumbnailView_LayoutTemplate.ascx?

Comment: Could you please test if it works after you split your Controls.Add to add the LayoutTemplate and the Group Template separatly?

Comment: You mean create a new container for the group control? I've tried that it doesn't work... As far as I know the container is simply a name referring to the list view... I'm beginning to think this is a microsoft bug